# Not able to invoke erase() operation in C++ vector<pair<>>

Tags: c++, vector

I'm not able to invoke the `erase` operation in `std::vector`. I don't know what went wrong and I've been trying to rectify it. I'm not able to understand what the error actually is. In the tutorials present on the Internet the `erase` operation seems to work but here it is not the case. I'm posting my code and relevant errors below.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::endl;
using std::pair;

bool ascSort(const pair<long long, long long> &a, const pair<long long, long long> &b) {
  return a.second < b.second;
}

vector<long long> optimal_points(vector<pair<long long, long long>> &segments) {
  vector<long long> points;
  long long n = segments.size();
  long long count = 0;
  while(n!=0) {
    vector<long long>::iterator it1 = segments.begin();
    long long firstNum = segments[0].second;
    for (long long i=1; i<n; i++) {
      if ((firstNum <= segments[i].second) && (firstNum >= segments[i].first)) {
        std::cout<<"YAYY"<<endl;
      }
      else {
        points.push_back(firstNum);
        segments.erase(it1, it1 + (i-1));
        break;
      }
    }
    count = count + 1;
  }
  std::cout<<count<<endl;
  return points;
}

int main() {
  long long n;
  std::cin >> n;
  vector<long long> first;
  vector<long long> second;
  for (long long i=0; i<n; i++)
    std::cin>>first[i]>>second[i];

  vector <pair<long long, long long>> segments;
  for (long long i=0; i<n; i++)
    segments.push_back({first[i], second[i]});

  std::sort(segments.begin(), segments.end(), ascSort);

  vector<long long> points = optimal_points(segments);
  std::cout << points.size() << "\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << points[i] << " ";
  }
}
```

And my errors are:

```
covering_segments.cpp: In function 'std::vector<long long int> optimal_points(std::vector<std::pair<long long int, long long int> >&)':
covering_segments.cpp:20:53: error: conversion from '__normal_iterator<std::pair<long long int, long long int>*,vector<std::pair<long long int, long long int>>>' to non-scalar type '__normal_iterator<long long int*,vector<long long int>>' requested
     vector<long long>::iterator it1 = segments.begin();
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
covering_segments.cpp:28:40: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::pair<long long int, long long int> >::erase(std::vector<long long int>::iterator&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<long long int*, std::vector<long long int> >)'
         segments.erase(it1, it1 + (i-1));
```

How should I rectify this issue?

Comment: `vector<long long>::iterator it1` -> `vector<pair<long long, long long>>::iterator it1`. Your types don't match. If this was intentional, please provide some clarification on why did you do that. If not, you are a victim of not using `auto` frequently enough :>

Comment: having a `vector<pair<long long, long long>>` why do you consider you have a vector of long long ? Look at what *pair* is

Comment: This is a compelling reason to use `auto` as the type of iterators and let the compiler deal with it. The actual type of the iterator is irrelevant to the programmer and specifying it explicitly only allows for errors like this to occur.

Comment: You can use `using TypeAliasName = ComplexType<Type>;` to shorten the name.

Comment: it is also very strange you complain about *erase* and bypass the error concerning the iterator ... take the errors into account in order without bypass, and also compile with high level of warning with the goal to have *no* produced warning

Comment: @Fureeish No it is not intentional. I'm not getting what to do. How do I rectify this?

Comment: @raviujjwal use *auto* or the right iterator type

Comment: @bruno I took vector of long long because for very long inputs it keeps working and don't fail the test case

Comment: @raviujjwal it seems you have to look at what an iterator is ...

Comment: @bruno I'm not getting the error actually. No intention to bypass it but solve it legally :) I'll try with auto.

Comment: @bruno @Fureeish I was not really familiar with iterator. Didn't knew something like `auto` exists. +1 for this. Solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this syntax:

```
vector<long long>::iterator it1 = segments.begin();
```

Putting a simple `auto` will deduce the type to `std::vector<std::pair<long long, long long>>::iterator` (exactly as that `begin` function has) – so both matches.

The second problem you've got with `erase()` will be fixed too, compiler previously detected an error in your code because there was no such overloaded function that supported `vector<long long>::iterator` type as an acceptable parameter – all errors were fixed just after changing the type. Here's the [live](https://onlinegdb.com/PNJo6gg_W) example of compilation without errors.